# Impact of skipping Step in CI/CD pipeline

Tags: testing, continuous-integration, sonarqube

I am relatively new to Software Development Life Cycle and recently set up a Jenkins CI/CD pipeline incorporating SonarQube as a static code analyzer. Below is an excerpt from my Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                script {
                    checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/main']], userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'git-url']]])
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Build Code') {
            steps {
                bat 'mvn clean package'
            }
        }
        stage('Static Code Analysis') {
            steps {
                withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'sonarqube', variable: 'SONAR_TOKEN')]) {
                    bat "mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.token=${SONAR_TOKEN} -Dsonar.host.url={sonar-url} -Dsonar.projectKey={project-key}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While setting up this pipeline, I pondered over what would happen if I skip a stage, say, "Build Code." Since Jenkins compiles the project during both the 'Build Code' and 'Static Code Analysis' stages, does it become redundant in this scenario? What potential implications or best practices should I consider when structuring my Jenkins pipeline stages for code compilation and static code analysis?Would be better If explained with examples why Build step is necessary

I attempted to create a Jenkins CI/CD pipeline with SonarQube integration. The provided Jenkinsfile excerpt includes stages for code checkout, code compilation ("Build Code"), and static code analysis. My specific concern was about the potential impact of skipping the "Build Code" stage, as both "Build Code" and "Static Code Analysis" stages seem to involve code compilation.

What actually resulted is that I'm uncertain about the necessity of having a dedicated "Build Code" stage when the "Static Code Analysis" stage appears to also involve code compilation. I'm seeking insights and best practices from the community to better understand the implications and considerations in structuring Jenkins pipeline stages for code compilation and static code analysis.

Answer (score 0):

The 'sonar:sonar' goal will not compile your code. Code compilation in this scenario is tied to the "package" phase that happens in the 'Build Code' stage.

Sonar makes use of [compiled code](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/analyzing-source-code/languages/java/) for java analysis, so you should not skip compilation.

You might want to have a look at this [guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) that explains the maven concepts of lifecycle, phases and goals and how those concepts relate to each other